# Combine class and page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, combine

I use [`combine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) class to bundle some LaTeX files together.

The main file is essentially like this:

```
\documentclass{combine}
\begin{document}

\begin{papers}
\import{file1}
\import{file2}
\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

A typical included file takes less than a page of text, but in the end every file is on a single page, as combine seems to be putting a page break after every file.  How would I avoid these page breaks?

Answer (score 5):

`\import`, like the standard latex `\include` requires each imported document to start on a new page. But if your documents are so small, you probably can just use `\input` instead and input the documents (which would need then just to be the document body without the preamble). If you need to process the documents individually as well as together there are various things you can do, hard to say without seeing an example but for instance if each small document was `doc1.tex`, `doc2.tex` etx and `doc`.tex` looked like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a,b,c}
\begin{document}
\input{doc1-body}
\end{document}
```

where `doc1-body,tex` is

```
stuff...
```

Then your combined document can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{a,b,c}
\begin{document}
\input{doc1-body}
\input{doc2-body}
\input{doc3-body}
\input{doc4-body}
\end{document}
```

Or possibly with section headings in between each document, or whatever you need....

Answer (score 4):

p.9 of the `combine` package documentation explicitly states

> In order to ensure that all material in an imported document is
>   typeset, there is an inbuilt `\clearpage` command within the imported
>   document's `\end{document}`.  Thus, any material after an `\import`
>   command will start on a new page.

Answer (score 1):

If the files you are wanting to put together in the same document all have a common preamble then you can use [docmute](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/docmute/docmute.pdf) to accomplish this.  Then the include and input commands behave as expected, with only the common preamble used.  If the individual documents are compiled they work as expected.  When combined then only the single common preamble is used.  (Formally the included (for page break)/inputted (included without page break) files preambles must be sublists of the main document preamble.  I mean a list not a set as the order of the \usepackage's can be important.)

I use this for syllabus preparation were I have about 30 standalone documents which I combine into the syllabai for 4-6 courses.  This allows me to edit and modify individual documents quickly both before the syllabus is published, but during the semester as changes have to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using docmute as suggested in one of the answers.  However, I still needed the following hack to avoid page breaks.

```
\let\clearpage\relax
```

Answer (score 0):

The following "hack" seems to work ... except that it apparently adds the class name of the imported document at the beginning.

```
\documentclass{combine}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\c@laenddocument}{% 
\@enddocumenthook \@checkend{document}% 
%\clearpage
\begingroup \if@filesw
\immediate\closeout\@mainaux \immediate\closeout\@partaux \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo \let\@newl@bel\@testdef \@tempswafalse
\makeatletter \input\c@lmainauxfile %% change here \fi
\c@lenddoca
\@refundefined \endgroup \deadcycles\z@\@@end}

\renewcommand{\c@lbenddocument}{% 
\@enddocumenthook 
\@checkend{document}% 
%\clearpage
\begingroup \if@filesw
\immediate\closeout\@partaux
\let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo 
\let\@newl@bel\@testdef 
\@tempswafalse \makeatletter \input\c@lauxfile
\fi \c@lenddoca
\endgroup \deadcycles\z@
\c@lclosetocs}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{papers}
\import{test1}\newline
\import{test2}
\end{papers}

\end{document}
```